# Remove repetitive values from array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i have a array of object to load some tasks for the user.

```
taskInfo =  [
    {name: 'John Doe', mail:'john@test.com', tasks: [
            {name:'Task1', priority: 1, groupname: 'gName'},
            {name:'Task2', priority: 1, groupname: 'gName1'},
            {name:'Task3', priority: 1, groupname: 'gName2'},
        ]
    },
    {name: 'Susan Doe', mail:'susan@test.com', tasks: [
            {name:'Task4', priority: 1, groupname: 'gName'},
            {name:'Task5', priority: 2, groupname: 'gName2'},
            {name:'Task6', priority: 3, groupname: 'gName2'},
        ]
    }
]
```

based on the above object, i have to create a dynamic value in the HTML page, following is the loop for create the layout

```
for(var j=0; j < taskInfo[i].tasks.length; j++)
        {
                var flow = taskInfo[i].tasks[j].parity;
                console.log(flow);
                var par = document.createElement("div");            
                par.setAttribute("id","Priority"+flow);
                cont.appendChild(par);
                }
        }
```

sofar all are working fine, but cannot avoid the repetition of the priority value.

```
<div id="priority1">..</div>
<div id="priority1">..</div>
<div id="priority1">..</div>
```

i want a single div instead of these repetition. help me to resolve this. i am a beginner to JavaScript.

Comment: What's "parity?"

Comment: Why not use your `name` properties for the div `id`? They seem to be all unique.

Comment: I have to list the tasks based on the priority...that's why i didn't consider other properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
...
var tmpList = []
for(var j=0; j < taskInfo[i].tasks.length; j++) {
    var flow = taskInfo[i].tasks[j].priority;
    console.log(flow);
    if (tmpList.indexOf(flow) < 0) { // if flow is not in tmpList
      tmpList.push(flow)
    }
  }
for(var k=0; k < tmpList.length; k++) {
  var par = document.createElement("div");            
  par.setAttribute("id","Priority"+tmpList[k]);
  cont.appendChild(par);
}
...
```

How about using a list for duplicate checks?

Comment: It really works well..thank you very much. could you explain how this conditional statement works?

Comment: The indexOf(`parameter`) method of `tmpList` returns the index of `parameter` in the list. The index of the list starts at zero, indicating that if the returned value is not greater than zero, it does not exist in that list. The `tmpList` stores the `priority` property of the object. If the `priority` exists using the method above, it is not saved. If this causes duplicate the `priorities`, only one is stored and used to render later.

Comment: Now i understood. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to keep the *parity* in a an array as you receive them and just check if the array already have a parity skip.

```
var parityArray = [];
for(var j=0; j < taskInfo[i].tasks.length; j++)
    {
            var flow = taskInfo[i].tasks[j].parity;
            if(!parityArray.includes(flow)){
                var par = document.createElement("div");            
                par.setAttribute("id","Priority"+flow);
                cont.appendChild(par);
                parityArray.push(flow);
              }
            }
    }
```

Comment: thanks. It works, but ie browser dosen't support this syntex.